# Magento 1.9.3 : Invalid login or password customer created on checkout

Tags: authentication, magento-1.9, registration, checkout

I m using Magento 1.9.3.

I am facing an issue when a customer is going to checkout and fill the billing form and do the whole process of checkout it shown login. and Admin it's is also in customer list, but when I logout that user / customer not able to login again. showing error:  Invalid login or password.

On the same time when I am trying to create customer normally means (customer/account) it's created successfully and login successfully there is no issue in it.

Can anyone guide me regarding this issue??

Comment: is it possible to share url?

Comment: Hi @Jinesh Brother Im working on my local machine for paymant I am using saved card.

Comment: Check in log folder is it any error for this issue